# JavaFX how to force Label to update its prefWidth after changing the text?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, layout

Pretty simple thing actually: I want my `Label` to update its `prefWidth` to fit the text into itself whenever the text changes.

Initially the `Label`s text is `null` and the `prefWidth` is `-1.0` without setting it manually. So when the `Label`s text changes at runtime the prefWidth is still `-1.0` and the `Label` displays "..." instead of the set text, because it is to small.

The `Label` is inside an `HBox`. That `HBox`s `prefWidth` is bound to the sum of its childrens `prefWidth`s and the `HBox` has enough space to grow.
Here's some code to reproduce:

```
public class Spielwiese extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Label label = new Label();
        Button button = new Button("Fill Label");
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Some Text"));
        HBox box = new HBox(label, button);
        box.prefWidthProperty().bind(label.prefWidthProperty().add(button.prefWidthProperty()));

        window.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(box)));
        window.setWidth(800);
        window.setHeight(600);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

How can I get the `Label` to update its width to fit its text?

EDIT: The root of the Scene is a `StackPane` not a `Pane`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? By default the preferred width of your `HBox` is computed as the sum of the preferred widths of it child nodes. All of these (label, button, and hbox) have `prefWidth` set by default to `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, which indicates they will calculate their own preferred size, and so everything should work without the binding. The actual value of the `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` constant is `-1`, so you end up setting these to `-2`, which has no meaning.

Comment: I want the HBox to be as wide its children together.

Comment: OK, so remove the binding. What you're describing is the default behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code: with the HBox being inside a StackPane, the HBox fills the StackPane and I want it to be just as big as it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to try to perform layout using bindings on the min/pref/max size of a pane. The `HBox` already knows how to compute its preferred width, and by default does exactly what you want (the simple version is it computes it as the sum of the preferred widths of its child nodes, though in reality it's more complex, as it accounts for spacing, padding, etc.).

The default value for `prefWidth` for both controls and layout panes is the sentinel value `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, which is just a flag to tell the node to compute its preferred size for reporting to whoever is laying it out. A label will compute its preferred size by checking the size required to display its text (and graphic), similarly for a button, and layout panes will examine the preferred sizes of their child nodes. The actual value of `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` [is `-1.0`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE), which is why you always see that value when you call `getPrefWidth()`.

The reason the `HBox` is being expanded to fill the stack pane is because that's exactly the behavior of a `StackPane`. From the [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html):

> The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content area.

You can prevent this either by using a different root pane, which doesn't have that behavior, (e.g. a plain `Pane` or another `HBox`, etc.):

```
public class Spielwiese extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Label label = new Label();
        Button button = new Button("Fill Label");
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Some Text"));
        HBox box = new HBox(label, button);

        window.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(box)));
        window.setWidth(800);
        window.setHeight(600);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

or by wrapping your `HBox` in another pane (so the pane in which it is wrapped will fill the `StackPane`, but your `box` won't fill its parent):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Spielwiese extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Label label = new Label();
        Button button = new Button("Fill Label");
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Some Text"));
        HBox box = new HBox(label, button);

        window.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(new HBox(box))));
        window.setWidth(800);
        window.setHeight(600);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

or by forcing the `box` not to grow beyond its preferred size, by setting its `maxWidth` to use the preferred size:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Spielwiese extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {
        Label label = new Label();
        Button button = new Button("Fill Label");
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Some Text"));
        HBox box = new HBox(label, button);
        box.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        window.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(box)));
        window.setWidth(800);
        window.setHeight(600);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

You didn't indicate in your question *why* you wanted to use a `StackPane` for the parent of the `HBox`. Since the sole functionality of a `StackPane` is to stack its child nodes on top of each other in z-order, if you're using a stack pane you're presumably adding other nodes on top of, or behind it. Consequently, it might actually not be necessary at all to prevent the `HBox` resizing (because it won't affect the stacking), but maybe it's enough just to ensure the alignment property of the `HBox` (and other child nodes of the `StackPane`) is set to the same as the `StackPane` (which is centered, by default). I.e. you might just need `box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)`.

Comment: The solution to setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE) works fine for my needs (want to stack the HBox on top of another Control, but want the box to be much smaller than the Control underneath it). Thank you :)